$V_+(I) \subset V_+(J)$ implies that $J \cap B_+ \subset \sqrt{I}$ for $\operatorname{Proj} B$
I am trying to understand the proof in Liu's book that $V_+(I) \subset V_+(J)$ implies that $J \cap B_+ \subset \sqrt{I}$, where $B$ is a graded ring, $V_+(I) = \\{ \text{homogeneous prime ideals containing $I$ and not containing $B_+$} \\}$, and $B_+$ is the irrelevant ideal.
Liu takes an arbitrary $\mathfrak{p} \in V_+(I)$, and, letting $\mathfrak{p}^h$ be the homogenization of $\mathfrak{p}$, says that if $\mathfrak{p}^h$ does not contain $B_+$, then $\mathfrak{p} \supset \mathfrak{p}^h$ and $\mathfrak{p}^h \in V_+(I)$. Thus $\mathfrak{p} \supset J \cap B_+$. On the other hand, if $\mathfrak{p}^h$ does contain $B_+$, then he simply states that we still have $\mathfrak{p} \supset \mathfrak{p}^h \supset J \cap B_+$.
I don't see how you get the second inclusion in the second case. If $\mathfrak{p}^h \supset B_+$, then we don't have that $\mathfrak{p}^h \in V_+(I)$, so how do we know in this case that $\mathfrak{p}^h contains $J$?
